# MySQL: How can I allow a CHAR row to be duplicate?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, duplicates

So I made a basic database with a table named "logs". In logs, I made a column (let's say "ID").
Next, I coded some PHP (`INSERT INTO logs (ID) VALUES ('$ID');`) and went to test it. I used the same value 2 times, and I got an error: `Duplicate entry`.
I knew this would happen, but is it possible to allow 2 or more rows to be the same in a `CHAR( 255 )` column?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your field a primary key?

Comment: no, it is not. And one thing I forgot to mention - I have 2 columns, not one, and both are CHAR columns

Comment: Your ID column must have the UNIQUE constraint. You should remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't make a field as primary key, or unique you can place duplicates there. The same applies for your Char(255) column.
Fields are by default not primary keys, and not unique. So, unless you change it yourself, duplicates are allowed.

Comment: Oh! Stupid me! I thought only unique fields can be duplicated. I am a bit new to MySQL, though! Thank you for the answer!